# Having issues understanding the notion of 2D volume in Measure Theory.

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

So the exercise I'm trying to solve goes like this:
P ⊂ $R^2$ is the interior of a parallelogram defined by its' corners coordinates:
(-2,1), (-1,3), (-3,3), (-4,1)
I need to find out $vol_2 (P)$

Now I found somewhere in a book that if the set I'm looking at is

$P=[a_1,b_1] \times [a_2,b_2]  \times ... \times [a_n,b_n]$ ⊂ $R^n$

then

$vol_n (P)$=$|b_1-a_1| |b_1-a_1|...|b_n-a_n|$

And I believe this finding may prove to be useful in what I need to solve, but I fail to identify the terms $[a_1,b_1]$ and $[a_2,b_2]$ in my scenario. Also, I don't really understand the concept of having a volume if this is a 2 dimensional figure.

Comment: Your formula won't work, because it's not a 2 dimensional cube. Also, specify your question. What options do you have to evaluate the area. You can obviously just use elementary school formulas, but I guess that's a no?

Comment: The author's note was that the formula is for any n-dimensional parallelepiped.
Yeah I'm not supposed to use elementary school geometry, but measure theory and the likes of Lebesgue integration.

Comment: I guess you can just integrate $1$ over your set? Would that do? Your formula doesn't exactly work here, it's not of the form like $P$

Comment: I have no idea sadly..

Comment: Did you cover double integrals?

Comment: Yeah I know how to do double or triple integrals, they werent a part of this subject but I know.

Comment: So, maybe try to cover your set with smaller and smaller "cubes" (squares in this case; 2 dimensional intervals), this way you'll find 2 dimensional Lebesgue's measure of your set, and from definition the result will follow. I don't really see other way to approach this with only this much information, maybe it was supposed to be exercise to understand Lebesgue's measure more clearly, or to check that it covers with what we know area is

Comment: Yeah theres the option of using dyadic cubes, I've used it before for when I am given a rectangle defined by 2 inequations such as

$1<=x_1<=3$
and

$2<=x_2<=3$

but I'm not sure how I'd go about using dyadic cubes on a parallelogram.